# Data updated in db but not in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I update an object using hibernate from db. But it doesn't change in the jsp page. I've to re-run the code (using eclipse) and then the jsp page is updated.

Following code displays data from database using hibernate. This page is not updated immediately when I update the database, even if this page is reloaded.

For example, I open this page, this page displays all the items in the database, I update the database and reload this page but it remains same. I've to re-run the jsp page using eclipse and then it's updated (i.e. change in database is reflected here).

```
<%!
Item item = new Item();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session_ = sessionFactory.openSession();
%>

<table id="t01">
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>       
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<%List itemsList = session_.createQuery("FROM Item").list();
for (Iterator iterator = itemsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
    item = (Item)iterator.next();
    out.println("<tr>" + "<td>" + item.getId() + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.getName() + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.getPrice() + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.getQuantity()  + "</td></tr>");
}
%>
```

Is there something that I add in jsp page and the jsp page will be **recompiled** every time it's reloaded?

Comment: Without the code it is hard to help, please add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should post you code so we can give you a more definitive and precise answer.

But if I understand you correctly it sound like you except that data on your JSP page to be bonded with you database, this is obviously not the case.

Your **text** in the JSP page is not magically **connected** to your database.
Its just text.

What you can do is change the text to match the new values programmaticly via JavaScript(Again give us your code so we can show you an example).

Or, a better solution would be to use some kind of a binding library like Angular or a simpler one like rivetsjs.

Edit:

If this is a browser cache problom then you can disable the cache by adding this lines:

```
<%
   response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
   response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
   response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 );
%>
```

source: http://www.xyzws.com/jspfaq/how-to-disable-browser-caching-for-a-specific-jsp/11

Comment: When I reload the page, it should get the data updated from database, right? But this is not the case.
I've added the code as well.

Comment: Then it probably browser cache you need to disable it via <meta> tags
But first try and use CTRL + F5 to reload the page.

Comment: How to do it using meta tag? Or is there something that I add in jsp page and the jsp page will be **recompiled** every time it's reloaded.

Comment: Those lines should be before the imports, even a new line character before them will make them useless. So edit your file to put those right on top and then follow imports or other tags.

Answer (score 0):

Besides David's answer which looking at your code and his should work you can try :
Also add some logging statements to make sure the correct code is runnong on server. another trick is to malke the requesk look like a get, so there is no caching.

Make a simple html form like:

```
<form action=yourJspPageName.jsp name=f1 method=get>
<input type=hidden value=1 name=r>
<input type=submit value=Refresh>
</form>
```

Instead of yourJspPageName put your page name, dont have to add path.